# Is that possible to use Http and Command livenessProbe in the same deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, health-check, livenessprobe

I just have a doubt on whether is possible to run multiples liveness probes in the same `deployment.yaml`.
For example: I already have a liveness probe that runs a python script that check my application like:

```
livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 5
  initialDelaySeconds: 15
  timeoutSeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 60
  exec:
    command: ["/usr/local/bin/python", "/app/check_application_health.py"]
```

Is that possible to include another liveness probe that check a `httpGet` healthcheck? Or should I include a `httpGet` healthcheck in this python script and run all in one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Currently its not possible,

as a workaround you can do something like this

```
"livenessProbe": {
         "exec": {
            "command": ["sh", "-c",
               "reply=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://< healthcheck url>); if [ \"$reply\" -lt 200 -o \"$reply\" -ge 400 ]; then exit 1; fi; /app/check_application_health.py;"
            ]
         }
      }
```

Source: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/37218#issuecomment-372887460